# Detect date format for Carbon::createFromDate

Tags: php, date, datetime, format, php-carbon

I have an API call that returns the date in various formats. I've written a try...catch block to try Carbon::parse and Carbon::createFromDate with multiple formats which seems to work, but I feel like there's gotta be a better way of going about this.

Here are two of the possible date formats:
2020-09-24T00:00.000Z
24/09/20 00:00:00

And here is the code I have

```php
// Test different date formats
$formats = ['d/m/y H:i:s', 'Y-m-d'];
$dateObj = null;

foreach ($formats as $format) {
    try {
        if ($dateObj = Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $date)) {
            break;
        }
    } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        $error = 'invalid date';
    }
    try {
        if ($dateObj = Carbon::parse($date)) {
            break;
        }
    } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        $error = 'invalid date';
    }
}
```

Comment: Do this only with createFromFormat. However, you must have all possible formats in the array. With Carbon :: parse incorrect results can be given. It is a demanding job. Information about the other formats is missing to be able to say more.

Answer (score 1):

`Carbon::parse()` is exactly made to parse various formats (it uses the `DateTime` native constructor) and you may rely on it to understand the more common formats. `createFromFormat()` is actually needed only when you have precise expectation or to be get a precedence when there is an ambiguity. For instance `1/2` is parsed by default in the US way (January 2nd), to get February 1st, here it's relevant to try first `createFromFormat()` with specifically `d/m` formats, but else `parse()` may be just enough. In your example `d/m/y H:i:s` indeed needs to be specified else the order won't be correct (and you can use `*` instead of the space so `T` would also work) but `Y-m-d` is useless, `parse()` handle it properly.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the Y-m-d from the formats array and it's working so far. I may come across other date formats I may have to add, but hopefully, it's just those two.